# Replace first occurring whitespace between two digits with slash

Tags: php, regex

I had expected the following regex to insert a slash between the `7` and the `25` in the following string: `unit 7 25 sample st smalltown abc 2015`

```
preg_replace("/(?<=\d) (?=\d)/", "/", $inputString);
```

Expected result:

```
unit 7/25 sample st smalltown abc 2015
```

Actual result:

```
unit 7 25 sample st smalltown abc 2015
```

Comment: Your regex is fine, but `preg_replace` **returns** the changed string so you need `$inputString = preg_replace("/(?<=\d) (?=\d)/", "/", $inputString);`

Comment: preg_replace is the return value of my function.  It may be a rendering issue or a compatibility issue.  The regex does appear fine, but when I echo the returned string there is no slash.

Comment: There must be something going on somewhere else in your code then because what you have works fine. If I try `echo preg_replace("/(?<=\d) (?=\d)/", "/", 'unit 7 25 sample st smalltown abc 2015');` I get `unit 7/25 sample st smalltown abc 2015` as expected.

Comment: @pcgben have you tried my answer? It works as far as I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $1 and $2 will hold the matching values and should be included in the replacement.

```
$str = "unit 7 25 sample st smalltown abc 2015";

Echo preg_replace("/(\d) (\d)/", "$1/$2", $str);
```

https://3v4l.org/o6UPC

Comment: Hey Andreas, it works as demonstrated above.  Unfortunately it is not working in my production environment.  I will need to do some more investigation.